# animate popup page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a popup with "Go Back" button on it. On click it will animate and display previous popup page.

Here is a markup

```
<div class="placeorder">    
    <div class="link">
        <a id="lnkPlaceOrder" href="#">Place Order </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="finalizePopoupBottomContainer">
    <button type="button" class="midBtn gray pullLeft" tabindex="9">
        <img id="img1" src="../Images/go-back-icon.png">
        <span class="finalizingGoBackBtn" id="btnGoBack">Go Back</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

`Place Order` link and `Go Back` button perform the same task

```
$('#btnGoBack,#lnkPlaceOrder').die('click');
$('#btnGoBack,#lnkPlaceOrder').click(function () {
    $("#divFinalizePopup2").empty();
    $("#divFinalizePopup2").css({ left: 0 });
    $("#divFinalizePopup1").css('left', '-1600px');
    $('#divFinalizePopup1').load('CustomerPages/FinalizePopup1.htm', function () {
        $("#divFinalizePopup1").animate({ left: "-800px" }, { duration: 1000, queue: true });
        $('#divPopup2,#divPopup').removeClass('downloadPopup');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Code works in Chrome & Firefox. but not in IE 11. It gives error `SCRIPT28: Out of stack space` when i click on GO Back button.

Note : Place Order link works in IE 11 though.

Comment: Is it possible that `die()` isn't properly unbinding?

Comment: @Thomas i tried commenting that part. it doesnt work anyhow

Comment: But I meant that it doesn't work while it should, commenting it gives it a 0% success rate ;) You could try calling plain `off()` to unbind all events (just for testing)